# Hangfire dashboard not displaying in a console application

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire, hosted

So I have Hangfire inside a console app that runs a background job simultaneously. I wanted to check the dashboard on the hangfire but it never appeared to me. Hangfire is executing well.

```
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{

.....

services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) =>
{
    var dbOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseOptions>>().Value;
    configuration.UsePostgreSqlStorage(dbOptions.Postgres.ConnectionString);
});

services.AddHangfireServer();

}).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
{
    builder.Configure(app =>
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new
            DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new AuthorizationFilter() }
            });
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();

        });
    });
});


var host = builder.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

I tried to access localhost:5000/hangire but no luck. My Authorization filter is this one:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        return true;
      
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: try adding this builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); and builder.Services.AddControllers();

Comment: so I added this as suggested:

 services.AddControllers();
 services.AddRazorPages();

 Before this:
 services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) => ...
 services.AddHangfireServer();

But still no luck

Comment: which version of .net are u using ?

Comment: I'm using net6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out for `.net8`.

UPDATE :
Same example works for `.net6`

First in your `csproj` add this :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then in my `Program.cs` :

```
var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions() { ApplicationName = "ConsoleApp1", EnvironmentName = "Development" });
builder.Host.ConfigureServices(
    (context,services) =>
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) =>
        {
            var dbOptions = "connection_string";
            configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(dbOptions);
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer();
    }
);
var app = builder.Build();


app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new
            DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new AuthorizationFilter() }
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

await app.RunAsync();
```

I thing that you were missing just include of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

NOTE :
I'm using `SQL Server` as persistance because I have already hangfire database ready.

NOTE 2:
Maybe it would be easier to have hangfire server configured as part of `.NET SDK Worker` and Dashboard UI inside the WebAPI.. Not sure what your use case is.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. The solution you provided creates a new ASP.NET Core app. However, I need to integrate it into my console app. The concept is to incorporate a background service within the console app to process data from a pipeline and periodically dispatch tasks to Hangfire for consumption, such as sending emails and storing events in the database. Therefore, I require the setup to involve Hangfire running alongside the console app, which in turn hosts the background service functioning as an ETL process.

Comment: I don't think that you can add hangfire dashboard UI then. You can have hangfire server inside the console app - but everything that you are trying to achieve is already awailable in .NET SDK Worker - Background service etc. And for Hangfire Dashboard UI you gonna need Web API. There are ways to add ti to .NET SDK Worker Service.

Comment: I saw this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800144/how-to-access-hangfire-dashboard-when-jobs-are-setup-via-console-application
And it's what I want to achieve but I still haven't figure it out since it's outdated

Comment: This is using Owin and they are using WebApp.Start<Dashboard>(options); This is part of Microsof.Owin.Hosting - Self Hosted WebAPI.